# In R, how do you use gIntersection on a spatialpolygon of buffered points and a spatialpolygon of census blocks?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

In R, how do you use gIntersection on a spatialpolygon of buffered points and a spatialpolygon of census blocks?

**Goal:** I want to find the number of people who live within a 800 meter radius of each senior center in New York City.

In spatialpolygon A below, I have 250 points, one of each senior center, each with a 800 meter buffer around them and attribute data.

```
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 255 
extent      : 921834.7, 1058046, 124227.6, 269527.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

In another spatialpolygon B below, I have longs and lats for each census block, a unique GEOID for each census block, along with other attribute data, including population data.

```
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 39148 
extent      : 921834.7, 1067384, 125227.6, 273618  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

How can I find the GEOIDs in spatial polygon B that are in each buffer zone in spatial polygon of A? It's matching problem in my mind. Put another away I'd like to have a data.frame, something like this below:

```
Generic GEOIDs from B   Buffernumberfrom A
1234567                 1
7654321                 1
1726354                 1
7162534                 2
0987655                 1
0891236                 1
```

My code for this is below, where you can see that I hit a wall as using gIntersection. For whatever reason, I can't get the over function to produce values another than NULL. I thought it was because the extents were different so I made them same. But that didn't help.

I would greatly appreciate any advice you  have in solving this challenge.

Thanks in advance.

I know, probably more libraries than I need but I at some point I loaded them all in to see if anything would help.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
require(rgdal)
library(plyr)
library(raster)
library(shapefiles)
library(gridExtra)
library("spatialEco")
library(rgeos)
library(maps)
require("sp")
require("raster")


set projection

projx <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs"

load in shapefile with demographic data by census block

setwd("/Users/Documents/cityblocks")

xx <- readShapePoly("/Users/Astro/Documents/cityblocks.shp", IDvar="GEOID10", proj4string=CRS(projx))

plot(xx)

read in csv that has the lat/long for the senior centers along with other data on each center

setwd("/Users/Documents")
another3 <-read.csv("fullscdata.csv")

use the same projection for the senior centers as I have for the census blocks in the shapefile 

map <- data.frame(project(cbind(another3$Long, another3$Lat), projx), another3)
create coordinates to be projected

coordinates(map) <- c("X1", "X2")

create buffer

bf <- gBuffer(map, width = 800, byid=TRUE, quadsegs=24)

see what buffer looks like
plot(bf)
head(bf)

set projection string for bf sam as xx

proj4string(bf) <- CRS(proj4string(xx))

gIntersects(as(bf, 'SpatialPolygons'), xx)

gIntersects(as(xx, 'SpatialPolygons'), bf)


tests indicated that the census blocks are not in the buffers or vice versa. compare xx and bf. is it saying bf not in the city because the extents are different?

xx
bf
```

messing around to with extents and geom types to see if that works. I thought the over function didn't compute values bc the extents were different and bc the two objects weren't stored as polygons. However, making the extents the same and making them both polygons did get the over function to produce values.
I also thought perhaps the extent of the polygon with the census blocks just needed to be bigger than the extents

for the polygons of the buffers. Sadly this was not a remedy.

```
ob <- SpatialPolygons(bf@polygons,proj4string=bf@proj4string)

ob1 <- SpatialPolygons(xx@polygons,proj4string=xx@proj4string)

proj4string(ob) <- CRS(proj4string(ob1))

ob1@bbox <- borobounds@bbox

ob1@bbox <- ob@bbox

x <- c(921834.7, 1067384)
y <- c(125227.6, 273618)

xy <- cbind(x,y)

S <-SpatialPoints(xy)

ob1@bbox <- bbox(S)

borobounds <- readShapePoly("/Users/Documents/bb/nybbwi.shp", IDvar="BoroCode", proj4string=CRS(projx))

check to see if census blocks are within the the buffers 

gIntersects(as(ob1, 'SpatialPolygons'), ob)
```

check to see if buffers are within the census blocks

```
gIntersects(as(ob1, 'SpatialPolygons'), ob)

borobounds <- readShapePoly("/Users/Astro/Documents/bb/nybbwi.shp", IDvar="BoroCode", proj4string=CRS(projx))

at some points I made a raster of ob1 but that didn't work either. 

I thought ggplotting them might provide some incite to what is wrong with the code. Something is wrong bc the census blocks 
and buffered zones don't plot together even though they have the same coord ref and same extents. 

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data=ob, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group), colour="yellow", size = 0.2) +

ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data=ob1, aes(x = long,  y= lat, group=group, fill="NA"), colour="blue", size = 0.2)
```

Here's how I wrote the gIntersection. I used drop_lower_td=TRUE bc when I didn't use it the first time I tried gIntersection, 
I received an error indicating that i should use it.

```
clip <- gIntersection(bf, xx, byid=TRUE, drop_lower_td=TRUE)
```

Comment: You really need to do your work first. Restate your question in a simplified form, using a reproducible example (that is, using data generated by code, or that comes with an R package). The question you are asking seems straightforward enough, but you complicated things by, for example, loading 12 packages, most of which are not relevant to the question. You also put text in code blocks.

Comment: Also, you cannot simple change the extent of a data set, you should _never_ assign values to the @bbox!. And, in fact, the coord ref systems are probably different. Again, you _set_ it to be the same, but that does not make it the same. Putting a post-it with 'computer' on it on a brick, does not change the brick into a computer. Instead of `readShapePoly` you should use `rgdal::readOGR` or the simpler `raster::shapefile`.